# Spring Database Authentication Exception Handling?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring authentication against an Oracle database for temporary users.  These users will be assigned a numeric ID that they can user to log into a limited web site.  Everything is working fine, but I just know that the users will at some point type in a user name instead of their numeric ID (I've done it myself while testing!).  Since the database column I'm authenticating against is a NUMBER, I get an ugly HTTP Status 401 page with a SQLSyntaxErrorException saying that what they typed in is an invalid number (which it is).

Is there a way to handle this gracefully?  For example, Spring has an ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler that allows you to map various types of authentication exceptions to web pages so you can redirect the user to a meaningful error page, and we're using that currently for things like BadCredentialsException.  It appears that you can't just use any old type of excpetion here, though, because I tried adding java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException and it didn't change anything.  Is there a similar Spring class that will allow you to catch other types of exceptions?  Or am I just not configuring that right?  Here's what I have:

```
<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler>
   <property name="exceptionMappings">
      <props>
         <!-- The Spring exception types all work fine... -->
         <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">
            /login/Bad Credentials
         </prop>
         <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">
            /login/Expired Credentials
         </prop>
         <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">
            /login/Account Locked
         </prop>
         <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException">
            /login/Account Disabled
         </prop>
         <!-- ...But this one doesn't do anything! -->
         <prop key="java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException">
            /login/Use Numeric ID
         </prop>
      </props>
   </property>
 <bean>
```

I'd really like to keep my database column defined as a number.  An easy solution would be to make it a VARCHAR but only put numeric data in it, but that's kind of ugly.  It would also be nice to have a unified way to handle all authentication exceptions, and we're already using the Spring handler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than dealing with the exception of having a string compared against a number you should handle this before it even get's validated. Possible options are:

1. Modify your login controller to reject attempts to login with non-numeric user ids. If you're using the built in controller in Spring Security this is probably more of a pain than option #2.
2. Modify your [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) to reject attempts to load users with non-numeric usernames. Have it throw a [`UsernameNotFoundException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UsernameNotFoundException.html) if the username is not valid.
3. Reject the login attempt purely on the client — this is generally a bad idea as things like this really should happen on the server side. I'm only suggesting it if modifying the server side is not possible. FYI, this would be just some Javascript regex validation before login form submission. This should work in most cases though it will *not* work if the client has Javascript disabled.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  I think I'll probably go for option #2, since now that you made me think about it we will need some more custom stuff in there anyway.